# makefile | condition | searching file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How can I do that wish with Makefile ?

```
 if ( file  exist in desktop )
      do X
 else
      mkdir folderName
      do X
```

platform linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a bash script function in your makefile like this:

```
define my_func
  if [ -e $(FILE) ] \
  then \
    <do x> \
  else \
    mkdir $(FOLDER_NAME) \
    <do x> \
  endif
endef
```

And then you can call in your target like this:

```
all:
    @$(call my_func)
```

`FILE` holds the path of the file you want to test the existence and `FOLDER_NAME` holds the path of the folder you want to create (as in the question above).

Comment: can you give explanation about how it works. Can i use your code segment with make ?

Comment: I explained a little better =) Does it help?

Answer (score 2):

```
all:
    $(if $(wildcard desktop/file),,mkdir foldername)
    do X
```

Explanation of `$(if)`: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-if-628

Explanation of `$(wildcard)`: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-wildcard-620